# GWT ClientBundle CSS doesn't use relative paths to reference images

Tags: jquery, css, gwt

I am new to Google Web Toolkit and am trying to use the ClientBundle in conjunction with jquery-ui. I have the project structure shown below:

[image: Project Structure]

I define a resource interface like this:

[image: Resource Interface]

I inject jquery and css like this:

[image: Inject]

Now, the CSS and JQuery script gets injected just fine. But, when I start the application the paths in the css are misinterpreted. The follow css line for example:

```
background: #eeeeee url(images/ui-bg_highlight-soft_100_eeeeee_1x100.png) 50% top repeat-x;
```

fails. Examples are shown below:

[image: Error]

As you can see, GWT somehow seems to assume that the images folder is a top folder but clearly this is not what I want. Should the images simply be placed under /war or do I have to include them in the client bundle as well? Or what is going on.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**1***
Use spriting as explained [here](http://www.gwtproject.org/doc/latest/DevGuideClientBundle.html)

use `@sprite` and `gwt-image` in your my.css file

```
@sprite .myImage {
  gwt-image: 'image';
}
```

and inject them in your app using bundles

```
interface MyResources extends ClientBundle {
  @Source("image.png")
  ImageResource image();

  @Source("my.css");
  CssResource css();
}
```

It won't get you there to inject jQuery Css.

**2***
A second option would be to write a little servlet which gives "direct url access" to your images, so you can keep the CSS as is.

Here is something I wrote to get CSS (not images) using Spring MVC. That should be enough to get the point. I'm using Spring's DispatcherServlet.

```
  private static final String CSS_PATH = "/path/to/my/css/resources/";
  private static final String CSS_EXT = ".css";
  private static final String CSS_CONTENT_TYPE = "text/css";

  @RequestMapping(value = "/resources/css", method = RequestMethod.GET)
  public void getCssResource(HttpServletResponse response, @RequestParam("name") String name) throws IOException {
    String path = CSS_PATH + name;
    InputStream is = SomeClassOnMyClassPath.class.getResourceAsStream(path + CSS_EXT);
    if (is != null) {
      flushResource(response, is, CSS_CONTENT_TYPE);
    }
  }

  private void flushResource(HttpServletResponse response, InputStream is, String contentType) throws IOException {
    DateTime expirationTime = new DateTime().plusDays(16);
    response.setContentType(contentType);
    response.setDateHeader("Expires", expirationTime.getMillis());
    IOUtils.copy(is, response.getOutputStream());
    response.flushBuffer();
  }
```

You can then get the CSS at the /resources/css?name=cssName url

Comment: I would prefer the option that let's me keep the css as it is. Can you elaborate on option number 2? Or is that a "hacky", bad solution?

Comment: It's not a hacky solution. But you'll loose GWT spriting capabilities. I edited the answer.

Comment: For a GWT project I'd advise to use plain GWT and (if possible) quit Js & JQuery. At least keep JSNI to a minimum.

Comment: Thanks. The reason for not using plain gwt is a bit tricky to explain. For normal usage I would use e.g. the gwtquery wrapper mentioned in the other answer.

Answer (score 1):

For proper jQuery integration with GWT, you should use [gwtQuery](http://code.google.com/p/gwtquery/).

it was written by [Ray Cromwell](https://plus.google.com/110412141990454266397/posts) (a GWT lead).

Answer (score 1):

Put all yours JQuery images files on the directory public in the same directory of the *.gwt.xml. (or your can add this line in the XML :

```
<public path="resources/jquery-ui-1.10.3/css/ui-lightness/" />
```

All theses files will be copied in the gwt js compiled files and the css will successful refer to the image.

There also are a wrapper to the JQuery UI in GWT : 
https://code.google.com/p/gwtquery-ui/
This project just import the JS file instead of the [gwtQuery](http://code.google.com/p/gwtquery/) which is a complete rewrite in GWT of the Jquery framework.